# update array of array object elements in mongoose

Tags: mongodb

I have schema data like below

```
{
    id:'5d60fd38f6999a7792c940a4'
    name:'test',
    department:[
        {
            d_name:'Rd',
            _id:'5d61092b1f234c11348eb831'
            equipements:[
                {
                    id:'5d637abd7ddd183263fa4ebc'
                    e_name:'first'
                },
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

and I'm try to update the equipments by following way

```
College.updateOne(
            {
                _id: productObjectID,
                'department._id': variantObjectId
            },
            { $set: data }
        );
```

but unfortunately this query is not update my equipment data .
can let me know what is right way to update. thanks

Comment: can you share what data you are trying to update?

Comment: I'm trying to change `e_name`

Comment: equipments is an array of objects, how are you determining which object from inside the array is to be upated?

Comment: I'm try to update equipemts by using `_id`. I don't know how to do that

Answer (score 0):

You need to search with the `equipements.id` in order to udpate the `name`

This would work

```
College.updateOne({
  _id: productObjectID,
  "department._id": variantObjectId,
  "department.equipements.id": equipementId
},{ "$set": {"department.equipements.$.name": "updatedName"} });
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume you're trying to achieve the below:

```
db.dummyTest.updateOne({ "_id" : ObjectId("5d63a1791b761bfc0420e590"), 
"department._id": "5d61092b1f234c11348eb831", 
"department.equipements._id": "5d637abd7ddd183263fa4ebc"  },
{ $set: { "department.$.equipements.0.e_name.0": "Update to last" }})
```

MongoDB's support for updating nested arrays is poor. So you're best off avoiding their use if you need to update the data frequently

Option 1: Make `department` its own collection (make department, as sub document instead of array)

Option 2: Achieve it through program